# How to let CiviCRM not send a confirmation to a new Mailing Group member?

Tags: civimail, profile

I added Groups to a Profile for a Contribution Page.

The public Mailing Group is nicely shown on the Contribution Page.
Can I prevent CiviCRM from sending a confirmation email?

It's on a Donation Contribution page with a IPN Payment Provider, so I can not use a webform for this page.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check this on the contribution page? There is an option there:
[image]

Comment: By the way, I know CatorgHans can read Dutch :-)

Comment: That is not the one. If you go to Profiles and add a profile with the "Group(s)"-field in it, you nicely see the Mailing Groups on the Contribution page where people can sign up to. But then you always get a confirmation email for those Mailing Groups. Those confirmation emails I want to switch off. Would that be possible?

Comment: I am lost on the Contribution page bit, but that might be because I hardly ever use Profiles :-) I will have to take a closer look but that will be tomorrow morning